# Why does this value return true at the end of the loop, and then false at the start of it?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Consider the following function which should draw an image to the canvas in chunks, cache those chunks, and then on the next loop check against those cached chunks to make sure we don't draw anything more then once.
If the console.log confirms that the cached chunk array is never cleared, why is it that when the result of `pixels.data == cachedImage[y][x]` is printed, it always returns `false`, but after updating the cache it reports as `true`?

```
async function temp() {
   const DIVIDE = 8;
   for(let y = 0; y < DIVIDE; y++) {
       if(cachedImage[y] == undefined) {cachedImage[y] = []; console.log(y);}
       for(let x = 0; x < DIVIDE; x++) {
           let widthChunk = (drawBuffer.width)/DIVIDE;
           let heightChunk = (drawBuffer.height)/DIVIDE;
           let pixels = ctx.getImageData(x*widthChunk,y*heightChunk,widthChunk-1,heightChunk-1);
           let pixeldata = pixels.data;
           debugBox3.innerHTML = (cachedImage[y][x] == pixels.data); // always "false"
           if(pixels.data == cachedImage[y][x]) {
           } else {
               cachedImage[y][x] = pixels.data;
               ctxFinal.putImageData(pixels,x*widthChunk,y*heightChunk)
           }
           debugBox4.innerHTML = (cachedImage[y][x] == pixels.data); // always "true"
       }
   }
}
await temp();
```

[(full file avaliable here)](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IoIxD/TerminalWars/TempBranchForDemonstrations/static/js/canvas.js)

Comment: You are asking why `cachedImage[y][x] == pixels.data` is true right after you set `cachedImage[y][x] = pixels.data;`???

Comment: I am asking why, when the loop goes again, `cachedImage[y][x] == pixels.data` is suddenly false.

Comment: Because it is a new location in the array? Isn't `data` an array, so your comparison needs to change.

Comment: It should not be, the old location should be replaced.

Comment: Arrays are Objects - so `ImageData.data` returns a reference to an Array Object. You cannot test equivalence of Objects using simple equivalence operators (`===`).

Comment: instead, you should use `Object.is(obj1, obj2)`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the following code:

```
let object1 = { key: 'value' }

var object2 = { key: 'value' }
```

One would think that `object1 == object2` is true, but its not. Why? Because object1 and object2 are merely references to objects - to independent objects that is.

However, if we extend the code:

```
let object1 = { key: 'value' }

var object2 = { key: 'value' }

object1 = object2
```

Now we have set the variable object1 equal to the reference to object2. We have not copied object2.

Therefore `object1 == object2` is now true.

When you say `cachedImage[y][x] = pixels.data;` you actually make `cachedImage[y][x]` a reference to `pixels.data`. Only then is it equal to pixels.data (which is also just a reference).

This is somewhat familiar to pointers in c, see:
https://www.sitepoint.com/how-javascript-references-work.

Comment: So how would I set the contents of `cachedImage[y][x]` to that of `pixels.data`?

Comment: use Object.is(obj1, obj2) instead of obj1===obj2

Comment: if you really wanted, you could say cachedImage[y][x] = { ...pixels.data } (if pixels.data is an object, else use [ ...pixels.data ]) but that would be horribly inefficient for memory reasons